# look forward to meeting

Tags: gerunds, participles, licensing

> “My daughter and I––and my dog, Enzo––would very much like to join you
>   for dinner in Maranello, then.”
>
> “Your dog is named Enzo? How propitious!”
>
> “He is a race car driver at heart,” Denny said, and he smiled at me. I
>   love Denny so much. I know everything about him, and yet he always
>   surprises me. He called Luca!
>
> “I look forward to ***meeting*** your daughter and to seeing Enzo
>   again,” Luca said. “I will have my assistant make the arrangements. It
>   will be necessary to retain your services under contract. I hope you
>   understand. The nature of our business, as well as the expense of
>   developing a test driver––”
>
> -- Garth Stein, The Art of Racing in the Rain

I guess the *-ing* form in *meeting* has the meaning of specific actuality, while in *[What had he hoped to achieve?](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/hope)*, to-infinitival has potentiality. And the former has internal aspect, while the latter external aspect as a whole. Is this what could be expected from the form?

Comment: Common expressions would be "I want to meet (someone)," but "I look forward to (some event)." So it's standard to say "I look forward to seeing/hearing/meeting ..." since you wish that event would happen at some point in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is merely a matter of licensing: *look forward to* and *anticipate* take a gerund, but *expect* takes the marked infinitive.

Note that phrasal verbs (or whatever you want to call them) whose final element is a preposition almost never take a marked infinitive, probably because the preposition+*to* collocation excites *horror aequi*.